# Is there any way of adding a GUI to a program I have already created, without re-designing the whole thing?

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface

I am relatively new to programming, well I have been programming in Python for about 6 months now due to taking Computing at A-Level. I believe that I have caused a disaster that influentially may cause me to drop marks and overall get a very bad mark in Computing.

One of the specification points that I must've not read was to create a GUI that is simple and easy to use (for the children using the program). I created and designed the program which took me months in IDLE getting ready to hand my coursework in before April the 11th, my deadline.

So my questions stands, is there a way that I can broadly 'add' a GUI to my script, or add one within a few days. I do not know how to use Tkinter and my program is 300 lines long.

Help please :-(

Comment: There is no way to copy-paste a complete UI into your program. Sit down, breath deeply, and learn `tkinter`. It's not that hard, you'll make it

Comment: 300 lines is quite a small program, if you already wrote it you can easily rewrite it with the GUI once you learned the GUI framework.

Comment: Thankfully you still have a month to go and now is an excellent opportunity to learn your favorite python widget library.

Comment: You should probably have a talk with a programming teacher about this.

Answer (score 3):

GUI programs are very different from command-line programs. A command-line program generally executes in a lineair fashion. A GUI program is event-driven. Event handler functions are called when e.g. a button is pressed or a menu is chosen.

Try separating your program into two files; a module that does the real work and a front-end that does the interaction with the user. Once you have made this separation, it should be relatively easy to add a GUI front-end.

If you want your program to basically work everywhere, stick to TkInter.

Comment: Thank you! This has cleared things up for me and made it not so daunting. I have split the files up, it became clear to about the inter face area and the actual functionality bit of my program. Appreciate it.